# How to set the save path for a file chosen in filechooser JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I searched around but couldn't find nothing on this.
I would like to set the save (destination) path for a file selected in Filechooser. For example, I selected a picture called 'test.jpg', I would like for this 'test.jpg' to be saved to C:\blah\blah\blah\Pictures. How can I pull this off? 
So far the code I have

```
public void OnImageAddBeer(ActionEvent event){

    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();

    //Set extension filter
    fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("JPEG Files (*.jpg)", "*.jpg"));
    File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if( selectedFile != null){



    } 
}
```

Comment: You want to copy or move the 'test.jpg' file?

Comment: Tightened wording.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
  Path target = Paths.get("c:/user/test", fileName);
  Files.copy(selectedFile.toPath(), target);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is copy the content inside the file choose in wherever you want, try something like this:

```
if(selectedFile != null){
   copy(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath(), "C:\\blah\\blah\\blah\\Pictures\\test.jpg");
}
```

and the method copy:

```
public void copy(String from, String to) {
    FileReader fr = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(from);
        fw = new FileWriter(to);
        int c = fr.read();
        while(c!=-1) {
            fw.write(c);
            c = fr.read();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(fr);
        close(fw);
    }
}
public static void close(Closeable stream) {
    try {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Basically `copy` just copy the content of the file located in `from` inside a new file located at `to`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this statement if you want to set the destination path:

```
fc.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Pictures"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this:

```
    String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File f = new File(dir + "/abc/def");
    fc.setInitialDirectory(f);
```